# How to solve ORA-39710 problem

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I've got an Oracle 10.2 database that I need to get up and running. I've googled but now I've run into a problem I don't know how to solve.
I've been told the database is a bit FUBAR, so expect many strange things...

Here is what I've done so far.

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on Fri Apr 7
Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  914358272 bytes
Fixed Size                  2100520 bytes
Variable Size             230687448 bytes
Database Buffers          675282944 bytes
Redo Buffers                6287360 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
```

Then I check the alert.log

```
Successful open of redo thread 1
Fri Apr 07 01:53:24 EDT 2017
MTTR advisory is disabled because FAST_START_MTTR_TARGET is not set
Fri Apr 07 01:53:24 EDT 2017
Errors in file /ora/product/10.2.0/db_1/admin/ora10/udump/ora10_ora_3031.trc:
ORA-00704: bootstrap process failure
ORA-39700: database must be opened with UPGRADE option
Error 704 happened during db open, shutting down database
USER: terminating instance due to error 704
Instance terminated by USER, pid = 3031
ORA-1092 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE OPEN...
```

And in the mentioned error file:

```
*** ACTION NAME:() 2017-04-07 01:53:24.252
*** MODULE NAME:(sqlplus@rh59 (TNS V1-V3)) 2017-04-07 01:53:24.252
*** SERVICE NAME:() 2017-04-07 01:53:24.252
*** SESSION ID:(159.3) 2017-04-07 01:53:24.251
Thread 1 checkpoint: logseq 29, block 2, scn 1119103
start recovery at logseq 29, block 2, scn 1119103
----- Redo read statistics for thread 1 -----
Read rate (ASYNC): 0Kb in 0.14s => 0.00 Mb/sec
Total physical reads: 4096Kb
Longest record: 0Kb, moves: 0/1 (0%)
Longest LWN: 0Kb, moves: 0/1 (0%), moved: 0Mb
Last redo scn: 0x0000.00111380 (1119104)
----------------------------------------------
----- Recovery Hash Table Statistics ---------
Hash table buckets = 32768
Longest hash chain = 0
Average hash chain = 0/0 = 0.0
Max compares per lookup = 0
Avg compares per lookup = 0/0 = 0.0
----------------------------------------------
*** 2017-04-07 01:53:24.398
KCRA: start recovery claims for 0 data blocks
*** 2017-04-07 01:53:24.398
KCRA: blocks processed = 0/0, claimed = 0, eliminated = 0
*** 2017-04-07 01:53:24.398
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 1 Seq 29 Reading mem 0
*** 2017-04-07 01:53:24.398
Completed redo application
*** 2017-04-07 01:53:24.398
Completed recovery checkpoint
----- Recovery Hash Table Statistics ---------
Hash table buckets = 32768
Longest hash chain = 0
Average hash chain = 0/0 = 0.0
Max compares per lookup = 0
Avg compares per lookup = 0/0 = 0.0
----------------------------------------------
ORA-00704: bootstrap process failure
ORA-39700: database must be opened with UPGRADE option
```

So I try UPGRADE

```
SQL> startup upgrade
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  914358272 bytes
Fixed Size                  2100520 bytes
Variable Size             230687448 bytes
Database Buffers          675282944 bytes
Redo Buffers                6287360 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
```

Fine! Lets create a user
    SQL> CREATE USER foo IDENTIFIED BY "bar";

```
User created.

SQL> grant create session to foo;
Grant succeeded.
```

And then
    $ sqlplus foo/bar

```
ERROR:
ORA-01035: ORACLE only available to users with RESTRICTED SESSION privilege
```

Google tells me to do
    $ sqlplus / as sysdba
    SQL> alter system disable restricted session;

```
System altered.
```

And then
    $ sqlplus foo/bar

```
ERROR:
ORA-39710: only connect AS SYSDBA is allowed when OPEN in UPGRADE mode
```

Now what?

I tried to do

```
SQL> shutdown
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  914358272 bytes
Fixed Size                  2100520 bytes
Variable Size             230687448 bytes
Database Buffers          675282944 bytes
Redo Buffers                6287360 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
```

I check the alert log and the referenced file tell me (again)

```
ORA-00704: bootstrap process failure
ORA-39700: database must be opened with UPGRADE option
```

Now what? shutdown/startup was not the solution. And I guess startup upgrade will just give me another 39710 error? How can I fix this?

Comment: How you ran into this situation? Was the last upgrade failed or something else?

Comment: Not realy sure, I think it was restored from some kind of backup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### 39700, 00000, "database must be opened with UPGRADE option"
>
> *Cause:  A normal database open was attempted, but the database has not 
>             been upgraded to the current server version.
>
> *Action: Use the UPGRADE option when opening the database to run 
>            catupgrd.sql (for database upgrade), or to run catalog.sql 
>           and catproc.sql (after initial database creation).

After `SQL> startup upgrade`, run the `catupgrd.sql`(if you were upgrading the database). The file can be found under `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin` directory.

After the completion it's execution `SQL>shut immediate` then `SQL>startup` then run `SQL>@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql`to recompile invalid database objects.

Comment: Thanks! Running catupgrd.sql went fine for most of the time, but then I got

    JVMRMACTION
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FULL_REMOVAL
    ...


    begin if initjvmaux.startstep('LOAD_JIS_JARS') then
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
        ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

    ERROR:
    ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE

And that is repeated a lot of times, and then:
    Enter value for locname:

Comment: And in the log it says:  ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [eokt2s_parse()+83] [SIGSEGV] [Address not mapped to object]

Comment: Current SQL statement for this session:
`begin if initjvmaux.startstep('LOAD_JIS_JARS') then

  dbms_java.loadjava('-noverify -resolve -synonym -grant PUBLIC lib/activation.jar lib/mail.jar'); 
  initjvmaux.endstep;
end if; end;`

Comment: Make sure that your `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$PATH` is set properly to point to the correct home.

Comment: The variables seems to be correct,
echo $ORACLE_HOME
/ora/product/10.2.0/db_1
[oracle@rh59 ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/ora/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin

unless they should point out some other oracle directory?

Comment: Yes, they seem fine.

Comment: Even if I got that error, I accept your solution since I can now login with foo/bar at least. 
I hope it was not something important that failed in the catupgrd script :)